# How do you remove the "draggable" attribut from an element once it's been dropped?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Good evening everyone. Still working on my DnD project, the DnD works satisfactorily but all the items stay draggable once they have been dropped. I would like to remove the draggable attribute once it has been dropped. How do I manage that? I have googled for severel hours before BTW. TIA Code follows...

```
$(function() {
  $(".tier").draggable({
    cursor: "grab",
    revert: true
  });

$(".target.droppable").droppable({
      accept: ".tier",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr("style", "margin: 0; border: 0;").appendTo(this);
        ui.draggable.attr("draggable", false);
        n = ui.draggable.attr("src");
        dr = ui.draggable.attr("draggable");
        console.log("Draggable:" + dr);
        // console.log("Image Filename:" + n);
        tn = n.substr(4, 1);
        // console.log("Tiernummer:" + tn);
        x = (this).cellIndex;
        // console.log("Dropped Index:" + x);
        index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        console.log("Dropped tr:" + index);
        t = parseInt(tn, 10);
        (this).setAttribute("draggable", false);
                checkright(t, x);
      }



});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class, so just remove the class like `ui.draggable.removeClass('draggable').removeClass('tier');`

```
$(".target.droppable").droppable({
      accept: ".tier",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr("style", "margin: 0; border: 0;").appendTo(this);
        ui.draggable.removeClass('draggable').removeClass('tier');
        ui.draggable.attr("draggable", false);
        n = ui.draggable.attr("src");
        dr = ui.draggable.attr("draggable");
        console.log("Draggable:" + dr);
        // console.log("Image Filename:" + n);
        tn = n.substr(4, 1);
        // console.log("Tiernummer:" + tn);
        x = (this).cellIndex;
        // console.log("Dropped Index:" + x);
        index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        console.log("Dropped tr:" + index);
        t = parseInt(tn, 10);
        (this).setAttribute("draggable", false);
                checkright(t, x);
      }
});
```

Comment: Dear Mr. @Kinglish ... I tried and the cursor changes as it should but when I hold the mousebutton long enogh I still can drag the item. Do you have any other useful insights that might help? But thanks for the prompt answer anyway.

Comment: Try the revised. I missed that you're actually setting the draggable based on the class `tier`, so that is also removed in the updated code.

Comment: Dear Mr. @Kinglish: That did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  $(".tier").draggable({
    cursor: "grab",
    revert: true
  });

  $(".target.droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".tier",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable.attr("style", "margin: 0; border: 0;").appendTo(this);
      dropped.draggable("destroy");
      n = dropped.attr("src");
      dr = dropped.attr("draggable");
      console.log("Draggable:" + dr);
      // console.log("Image Filename:" + n);
      tn = n.substr(4, 1);
      // console.log("Tiernummer:" + tn);
      x = $(this).index();
      // console.log("Dropped Index:" + x);
      index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
      console.log("Dropped tr:" + index);
      t = parseInt(tn, 10);
      $(this).attr("draggable", false);
      checkright(t, x);
    }
  });
});
```

It is best to use `destroy` for any jQuery UI object. See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy

> Removes the draggable functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.